# AS3 Accessing a variable from an external include ActionScript File .AS not Class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, include

i am loading in a external AS file directly into the main timeline IDE using the "include" method with some variables and calling another Class within the AS file for example;

```
include "vars.as"
```

contents of "vars.as":

```
var test:* = "test?!";

var foo:FOO = new FOO();
addChild(foo);
```

contents of "FOO.as":

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;

    public class FOO extends MovieClip {

        public function FOO() {

            trace("test= "+test);
        }
    }
}
```

**error;**
1120: Access of undefined property test.

how can i access the "test" variable inside "vars.as" from the "foo" class, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i found a solution, hope this helps someone else out there.

**this is how you should call it from the main timeline;**

```
var foo:FOO = new FOO(this, stage);
addChild(foo);
```

**and here is the updated FOO class:**

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;

    public class FOO extends MovieClip {

        var _stage:Stage;
        var _root:*;

        public function FOO(root:*, stage:Stage){
            this._stage = stage;
            this._root = root;
            trace(this._root.test);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i would not recommend using this method, causes issues so i just moved and converted all the code to AS3 Document class. it's easier to manage the code..

Answer (score 0):

Included actionscript files, during compilation, are treated as though they were right in the body of the actionscript you included them in. You can just access them normally as though you defined them in the same place.

trace(test); //test

Comment: that does not work i wish it was that simple, "1120: Access of undefined property test." - i need to call "trace(test)" from Foo (which is a Class which extends as a MovieClip).